# Kubectl Unknown apiVersionKind batch/v1/Job is it registered?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to create a job from pod in minikube. Below is my `job.yaml`. I am using `client-java-11.0.0` API. When I run the application from IDE, it creates the job. I load the file using `Yaml.load(file)`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: mansoor-hello-world-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mansoor-hello-world-job-image
          image: job/mansoor-hello-world-job
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      #          command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Now this application I am running in a container. When I do `Yaml.load(file)` I get below error `Unknown apiVersionKind batch/v1/Job is it registered?`. Any idea?

Below is my deployment.yaml for the app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: job-runner-pod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: job-runner-pod-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: job-runner-pod-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: job-runner-pod
          image: pods/job-runner-pod
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
#          command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
```

Comment: What does the client code actually look like?  In `k8s.io/client-go` I know there's an internal "scheme" system where the controller needs to know up front about a group/version/kind it's going to use, and potentially something like that is producing the error you're seeing.

Comment: I am using `client-java` and it is like 
`V1Job body = (V1Job) Yaml.load(file); //load static yaml file

        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);`

Comment: What is your kubernetes server version?  run `kubectl version` and include the output.  Also run `kubectl api-resources` and see if Job is in the list (it should be)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, your `Job` object is not being correctly "detected" as `Job` kind by the client library. According to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/221) on the GitHub issue board of the `java-client`, you can specify the model of the object before loading it as a file.

```
Yaml.addModelMap("batch/v1/Job", V1Job.class)
```

Afterwards, when you load your YAML, it will be interpreted appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. But the addModelMap is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to craete docker image, the jar had issues. I was able to fix the issue like below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <includes>
                        <include>
                            <groupId>non-exists</groupId>
                            <artifactId>non-exists</artifactId>
                        </include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                            <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And in `Dockerfile` used command like `CMD ["java","-Dloader.path=/app/lib","-jar","/app/app.jar"]`

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY target/lib /app/lib
COPY target/*.jar /app/app.jar
CMD ["java","-Dloader.path=/app/lib","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```